# Allow user moving specific topic up and down in an interactive mode

Tags: django

In Django's template, I could list some topic as below:

[image]

with codes:

```
<ol>
    {% for topic in topics  %}
            <li>
                <h5>
                    <a href="{% url "learning_logs:topic" topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a>
                </h5>

            </li>
    {% endfor %}

</ol>
```

The problem is that they are read-only to the users.
How to allow user moving specific topic up and down to resort them?

Comment: you should use `js` or create backend point to update topic posion with refresh your page.

Comment: Are there cases I can reference? @BearBrown